# Someones know a better option to print this variables?

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I'm looking for print some variables more quickly. The code that i'm using is:

```
A_PR=3
B_PR=4
C_PR=6
print('the value of the model A is:', A)
print('the value of the model B is:', B)
print('the value of the model C is:', C)
```

I was thinking in a loop with a the for, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you would have to access those variables by names that are stored in another variable. Some people call it "dynamic variable names". One option, once again if you *really* want to do it, is to use `globals()`:

```py
for x in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    print(f'The value of the model {x} is:', globals()[x + '_PR'])

# The value of the model A is: 3
# The value of the model B is: 4
# The value of the model C is: 6
```

But it is *not* recommended: see [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables).

So one of better options might be to use an iterable data type, such as `dict`:

```py
models = {'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 6}

for x in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    print(f'The value of the model {x} is: {models[x]}')
```

---

It can be further simplified using `items`, although I am not a huge fan of this, if I want to preserve the order.

```py
models = {'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 6}

for k, v in models.items():
    print(f'The value of the model {k} is: {v}')
```

(A `dict` does preserve the order, but in my mind, I treat `dict` as not being ordered conceptually).

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting like this:

```
A_PR=3
B_PR=4
C_PR=6

print('Model A: {} \nModel B: {}\n Model C: {}'.format(A_PR, B_PR, C_PR))
```

Or you could embed those values into a array and loop over that array. Using ASCI values you can print A - Z model results

```
A_PR=3
B_PR=4
C_PR=6
model_results = [A_PR, B_PR, C_PR]

for idx, result in enumerate(model_results):
    print('Model {}: {}'.format(chr(idx + 65), result))
```

Output:

```
Model A: 3
Model B: 4
Model C: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    model_dict = {'A':3, 'B':4, 'C':6,}
    for k,v in model_dict.items():
        print(f"the value of model {k} is: {v}")
```

Here's a simple solution I whipped up using python [f strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) and a [dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work as a small dictionary with a for loop. Simply unpack keys and values.

```py
PR = {
    "A_PR": 3, "B_PR" :4 , "C_PR":6,
}

for k,v in PR.items():
    print(f'the value of the model {k} is: {v}')
```